# Get taxonomy name by tax-query in posts list

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have ajax category filtering and I use it to get taxonomy id and list posts by taxonomy. Now I want to show current taxonomy name in list view.

I have trying to add `<h4>get_cat_name((int)$category)</h4>` above of `<div class="list">`, but nothing is displayed. The posts will be listed correctly, depending on which taxonomy I click on the frontend. How I can print category name below posts list?

```
function ajax_filtering() {

$category = esc_html($_POST['category']);

$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order' => 'ASC'
             );

if ( isset( $category ) ) :
     
     $args['tax_query'] = 
     array( 
         array( 
               'taxonomy' => esc_html($_POST['taxonomy']),
               'field' => 'id', 
               'terms' => array((int)$category) 
             ) ); 
endif;
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<div class="list">

<?php

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
       $the_query->the_post(); 
      

 ?>
        <div class="post">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-link">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?>
                    <h4 class="post-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: ``echo`` the value of ``$category`` and see what does it print.

Comment: Try this: get_term_by('id', $category, 'category')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_term_by()`. Add this below code above of `<div class="list">`

```
$category = get_term_by('id', $category, $_POST['taxonomy']);
echo '<h4>'.$category->name.'</h4>';
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [get_term_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.